# call psql function after table creation

Tags: postgresql

I have .sql file in which I am creating a table and inserting rows.

```
CREATE TABLE vehicle (  
    name              TEXT    PRIMARY KEY,    
    id INTEGER DEFAULT 0  
)  
INSERT INTO vehicle values('car',1);  
INSERT INTO vehicle values('bus',2);
```

Instead of executing insert commands I want to have a function which will do the inserting above two rows. How I can call the function?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert()  
        RETURNS VOID AS $$  
BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO vehicle values('car',1);  
INSERT INTO vehicle values('bus',2);  
        RETURN;  
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: `select insert();`

Comment: Just try to choose some another name for your function

Comment: Whether the function definition should be added before and then call   select insert();

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need such a function?
Probably, all you need is just to wrap everything into single transaction block?

```
begin;
  CREATE TABLE vehicle (  
    name              TEXT    PRIMARY KEY,    
    id INTEGER DEFAULT 0  
  );
  INSERT INTO vehicle values('car',1);  
  INSERT INTO vehicle values('bus',2);
commit;
```

?

If no, consider using "anonymous" plpgsql block, w/o defining a function exclicitly -- it's useful when you need to run some code only once:

```
do $$
begin
  INSERT INTO vehicle values('car',1);  
  INSERT INTO vehicle values('bus',2);
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Finally, if you do need a function, ok, you defined it correctly, so let's run it. In Postgres, stored procedures are *functions*, what means that they can easily be integrated into regular SQL statements, so let's just use SELECT (in Postgres, SELECT statements are allowed to have no FROM clause):

```
select insert();
```